# How to compile Obj-C graphical Hello World inside iPod Touch (iOS 5.1)

Tags: ios, compilation, jailbreak

The iDevice is an Ipod Touch 4 (ios 5.1), with redsn0w jailbreak. I have no Mac's.
So far I've been able to compile and run a C hello world through PuTTY.

What I want to do is to compile an Objective-C graphical hello world, and then install it so I can execute it from SpringBoard.

I followed the (old) instructions [here](http://antirez.com/page/iphone-gcc-guide.html), from antirez blog.
Steps are:

1. Log into the iPod with PuTTY and SSH.
   (Through SSH)
2. Download SDK 2.0 headers to iPod (using `wget`). Extract, then move to `/var/include`
3. Downoad, extract [this](http://antirez.com/misc/iphone-helloworld-1.tar.gz) source code example. I'm good so far.
4. Run make.

Output is:

```
arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -c -I"/var/include"  -I"/usr/include"  -F"/System/Library/         Frameworks"  -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"  -DDEBUG -Wall -std=c99 -DMAC         _OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050 Classes/HelloWorldApp.m -o Classes/HelloWorldApp.         o
arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -c -I"/var/include"  -I"/usr/include"  -F"/System/Library/         Frameworks"  -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"  -DDEBUG -Wall -std=c99 -DMAC         _OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050 Classes/main.m -o Classes/main.o
arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -arch arm -lobjc  -framework CoreFoundation  -framework Fo         undation  -framework UIKit  -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics  -fram         ework GraphicsServices  -framework CoreSurface  -L"/usr/lib" -F"/System/Library/         Frameworks" -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" -bind_at_load -multiply_define         d suppress -o HelloWorld Classes/HelloWorldApp.o Classes/main.o
ld: library not found for -lobjc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1
```

Now, if I erase that `-lobjc`, I realize that none of the other libraries (for example CoreFoundation) are actually being included in the compile process.

a) How do I fix this? or... Am I trying to do something impossible?
b) Does being in iOS 5.1 make it more harder to develop programs?

I heard that I need the entire Apple SDK to compile. So suppose I download it.
c) Should I download it onto the iPod? Into which path exactly?

Comment: 2.0 SDK?  As in iOS 2.0?  You realize that it is 3 1/2 years old now....right?  I wouldn't expect any of this to compile correctly after three major revisions and an architecture change.  You are probably going to have to find a device running iOS 2.0 (or at least 2.x).